# Scatter detection delay issue

Tags: eosjs, javascript, scatter

I am working on developing a web app in EOS. I am using scatter browser extension to sign the transactions.
During page load, the status of scatter is checked using the following code

```
const setStatus = () => {
        const status = document.getElementById('status');

        if(!scatter) {
            status.innerText = 'Please install scatter';
        }

        else if(!scatter.identity) {
            status.innerText = 'No identity selected';
        }

        else{
            status.innerText = scatter.identity.name;
        }
    };
```

But during the page load, the scatter is not detected and `(!scatter)` condition is satisfied even if my scatter is all set. Is there any solution to detect scatter on page load instantly?

Answer (score 0):

From the [ScatterJs GitHub-Repository](https://github.com/GetScatter/scatter-js):

**Connect to an available wallet**

Once you are connected you can then call API methods on *ScatterJS*

```
ScatterJS.connect('MyAppName', {network}).then(connected => {
    if(!connected) return false;
    // ScatterJS.someMethod();
});
```

[You can see full scatterjs-core API docs here](https://get-scatter.com/docs/api-reference)